# I am spawning a sprite inside of setInterval and want it to bounce of walls

Tags: javascript, code.org

I am spawning sprites inside of setInterval, and want them to bounce off of walls.

my current code looks like: https://studio.code.org/projects/gamelab/HthFm5-YlmsJ93_qaT9vmPlVObvkXnxx5YNkk2OZPuY

I have tried creating the wall sprites outside of setInterval but the bullets simply pass right through them, as shown here: https://studio.code.org/projects/gamelab/t1DyjL1A7TiZWKYI1w2FBA-PvDR2i9WSsYPDjJcRWIY

How do I make the bullets bounce off of the walls?

Answer (score 0):

```
sprite.bounceOff(target);
```

You Would Need To Use This

BALL.bounceOff(WALL)

**EDIT :**
I Just Looked At Your Code
Move

```
      bullet.bounceOff(wall1);
      bullet.bounceOff(wall2);
```

Into Your Draw Function, This Code Isn't Always Active

Add It To A Group